# preg_replace always gives link to the same page as $1

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am using preg_replace in PHP. When i use this code line:

```
echo nl2br(preg_replace("(http://.+) ", "<a href='$1'>[link]</a>", $row['description']));
```

It echoes `"<a href=''>[link]</a>".`
Here is the "description": http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JDrnz8ZZtUE 
What is wrong with this? (I also included the space in the description)

Comment: Your regex is missing delimiters.

Comment: Your regex is missing its delimiters `/(http:\/\/.+)/` Or `|(http://.+)|`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you didn't specify delimiters. PHP will assume the `()` to be delimiters, thus eliminating your capture group.

```
"~(http://.+)~"
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any delimiter. Here is the syntax :

```
$pattern = '/(\w+) (\d+), (\d+)/i';
```

Try to do like this :

```
echo nl2br(preg_replace("/(http://.+)/", "<a href='$1'>[link]</a>", $row['description']));
```

Comment: Where did you find this syntax from? And if you use `/` as delimiters, you need to escape it inside of the pattern itself, (`http:\/\/`).

Comment: Just got it from here : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-replace.php

Bur you're right for the escape, sorry